# Does index rebuilding + updating statistics actually fix the issue of skewed cached plans?

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, sql-execution-plan

**Background**

We have an export functionality which allows the user to export measurements from many devices for a certain time range.

The database is continuously being updated with sensor data from many devices (at 10 to 50 measurements per second from each device). So since these CSV exports often contain millions of rows (each row containing data from several different devices, where each device is in a separate database), it was written to fetch data from these tables in chunks (I guess to avoid slowing down inserts, since exporting is a lower priority task).

**Problem**

When the first chunk is queried, SQL Server will create an execution plan which fits the passed parameters. However, at the beginning of the export, it's possible that ranges of data are missing due to low connectivity, or are flagged differently due to time sync errors, meaning the following queries reusing this cached plan will possibly not get the optimal plan for their parameters.

One option is to add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to each query, but many sources claim that this will impose unnecessary burden on the CPU and that merely updating statistics on a regular base should help SQL Server create a better plan.

However, this doesn't make too much sense, because even if the plan cache is invalidates, the next time a user creates the query, first chunk will again dictate the "shape" of the execution plan.

**Is this reasoning correct?**

Should I actually use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` with each query, or just add an "Update Statistics" maintenance plan?

Comment: May help to see the search clauses/params you are using

Comment: My first choice would be `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. Then I'd measure the impact of different approaches. You may need to have both `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` and update statistics.